# Painel não consigo dar um Visible=true nele

Tags: c#

Tenho um painel e dentro dele um repeater com uma table. Esse painel está dentro de um user control. Uso esse UC em várias situações. Criei um método chamado `AplicarCaracteristicas`, para dependendo do chamador, ele vai ou não mostrar alguns controles. Isso funciona muito bem. Houve a necessidade de eu criar mais um repeater dentro dele. Então criei um Panel e dentro dele coloquei o repeater. No método `AplicarCaracteristicas`, eu então dei um visible = true e no break eu vou ver o valor e está `false` e não `true`. Abaixo meu Panel e meu método `AplicarCaracteristicas`. Preciso que ele seja mostrado apenas em Bens Usados. O panel se chama pnlGrupoCota.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlGrupoCota" runat="server" Visible="true">
            <asp:Repeater ID="rptGrupoCota" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Grupo/Cota</th>
                            <th>Crédito Disponível</th>
                            <th>Crédito Pendente</th>
                            <th>Crédito Associado</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                </HeaderTemplate>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>

                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblAnoMod" runat="server" Text="Testando 1"/></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblAnoFab" runat="server" Text="Testando 1" /></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblValorPedido" runat="server" Text="Testando 1" /></td>
                        <td><asp:Label ID="lblAlienado" runat="server" Text="Testando 1" /></td>

                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

            <FooterTemplate>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Meu método

```
public void AplicarCaracteristicas()
        {
            //Declarações



            try
            {
                //Instâncias e Inicializações


                //Desenvolvimento
                switch (hdfConfiguracaoWUC.Value)
                {
                    case "1":

                        //Label do Formulário
                        lblNomeFormulario.Text  = "Bens Novos";

                        //Mostra Campos 
                        pnlFornecedor.Visible   = true;

                        //Esconder Campos não utilizados
                        cmbCdUFOrigem.Visible   = false;//Combo da UF de Origem
                        lblIcNovo.Visible       = false;//Label Veiculo Novo
                        rblIcNovo.Visible       = false;//Indicador de Veiculo Novo
                        lblUfOrigem.Visible     = false;//Label da UF de Origem

                        pnlGrupoCota.Visible = false;

                        //Esconder Botões não utilizados

                        break;

                    case "2":

                        //Label do Formulário
                        lblNomeFormulario.Text  = "Bens Usados";

                        //Mostra Campos 
                        pnlFornecedor.Visible   = true;
                        lblIcNovo.Visible       = true;//Label Veiculo Novo
                        rblIcNovo.Visible       = true;//Indicador de Veiculo Novo
                        lblUfOrigem.Visible     = true;//Label da UF de Origem
                        cmbCdUFOrigem.Visible   = true;//Combo da UF de Origem

                        //Mostra o grid de Grupo e Cota
                        pnlGrupoCota.Visible = true;


                        //Esconder Campos não utilizados

                        //Esconder Botões não utilizados

                        break;

                    case "3":

                        //Label do Formulário
                        lblNomeFormulario.Text  = "Confissão de Dívida";

                        //Mostra Campos 
                        lblIcNovo.Visible       = true;//Label Veiculo Novo
                        rblIcNovo.Visible       = true;//Indicador de Veiculo Novo
                        lblUfOrigem.Visible     = true;//Label da UF de Origem
                        cmbCdUFOrigem.Visible   = true;//Combo da UF de Origem

                        //Esconder Campos não utilizados
                        pnlFornecedor.Visible   = false;

                        pnlGrupoCota.Visible = false;


                        //Esconder Botões não utilizados

                        break;
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Só para agregar, fiz o painel true para todos e mesmo assim ele não é exibido.

Comment: No debug entra no `case "2":` e não exibe? O painel é renderizado no código da pagina normalmente?

Comment: seria melhor você associar a propriedade style.display nele já que houve um bug ao alterar a propriedade!

Comment: Entra sim, no case 2. Mas não consigo atribuir true ao painel.

Comment: Interessante que em design eu consigo visualizar o grid

Answer (score 0):

Aplique o visible true no page load

```
if(!Page.IsPostback)
{
   pnlGrupoCota.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Já sei o que pode ser. No page load não seria possível, porque senão ele estaria visível para todos e ele só pode estar visível dentro o Panel Usados. Acho que faltou o Datasource do Repeater. Até passa pelo visible=true, mas sem dados do repeater nada vai mostrado e o repeater, pelo que entendi, não se torna visível em runtime com dados fixos, pelo menos foi o que me disseram no SO.